# RTK type Error when using injectedEndpoints with openApi

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I define config file for openApi to create automatically endpoints with types:

```
const config: ConfigFile = {
  schemaFile: 'https://example.com/static/docs/swagger.json',
  apiFile: './api/index.ts',
  apiImport: 'api',
  outputFile: './api/sampleApi.ts',
  exportName: 'sampleApi',
  hooks: true,
}; 
export default config;
```

I used :

```
"@rtk-query/codegen-openapi": "^1.0.0-alpha.1"
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.2",
```

Then I define an index.tsx that has

```
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '' }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

and So I generate successfully my sampleApi.tsx file with all of endpoints and types.
like here:

```
    const injectedRtkApi = api.injectEndpoints({
      endpoints: (build) => ({
         postUsersCollections: build.mutation<
      PostUsersCollectionsApiResponse,
      PostUsersCollectionsApiArg
      >({
      query: (queryArg) => ({
        url: `/users/collections`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: queryArg.postCollectionBody,
      }),
    }),
    getUsersCollections: build.query<
      GetUsersCollectionsApiResponse,
      GetUsersCollectionsApiArg
    >({
      query: (queryArg) => ({
        url: `/users/collections`,
        params: { name: queryArg.name },
      }),
    }),
    overrideExisting: false,
});
export const {
  usePostUsersCollectionsMutation,
  useGetUsersCollectionsQuery
} = injectedRtkApi;
```

1. when in a component I use hook function `useGetUsersCollectionsQuery` as bellow I got an error that  `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscriptions')`. There is no lint typescript error related to typescript in my project.

```
const { data: collectionData = [] } = useGetUsersCollectionsQuery({});
```

It's Interesting that this hook called and I see API call in network tab but immediately I got this error. I remove this line and error is disappeared.

2. And Also for mutation hook I send data within it but I got 400 error. as Below:

```
const [postCollection, { data: newCollect }] =
    usePostUsersCollectionsMutation();
    ...
    const handleCreateItem = async () => {
      const response: any = await postCollection({
        postCollectionBody: { name: 'sample' },
      }); }
```

Please help me! I really thanks you for taking time.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I resolved it!
I should define reducerPath as this:

```
export const api = createApi({ 
   reducerPath: 'api',  <=== add this and define `api` in reducers
   baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '' }),
   endpoints: () => ({}),
 });
```